# php array syntax ${ is confusing me

Tags: php, html, arrays

I create a $values array and then extract the elements into local scope.

```
 $values['status'.$i] = $newStatus[$i];
 extract($values);
```

When I render an html page.  I'm using the following

```
 <?php if(${'status'.$i} == 'OUT'){ ?>
```

but am confused by what the ${ is doing and why $status.$i won't resolve

Comment: This is a "variable variable"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$status.$i` means

> take value of `$status` variable and concatenate it with value of `$i` variable.

`${'status'.$i}` means

> take value of `$i` variable, append id to `'status'` string and take value of a variable `'status'.$i`

**Example:**

With `$i` equals `'2'` and `$status` equals `'someStatus'`:

- `$status.$i` evaluated to `'someStatus' . '2'`, which is `'someStatus2'`
- `${'status'.$i}` evaluated to `${'status'.'2'}` which is `$status2`. And if `$status2` is defined variable - you will get some value.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add to the accepted answer with a suggested alternate way of achieving your goal.

#### Re-iterating the accepted answer...

Let's assume the following,

```
$status1 = 'A status';
$status = 'foo';
$i = 1;
$var_name = 'status1';
```

and then,

```
echo $status1; // A status
echo $status.$i; // foo1
echo ${'status'.$i}; // A status
echo ${"status$i"}; // A status
echo ${$var_name}; // A status
```

The string inside the curly brackets is resolved first, effectively resulting in `${'status1'}` which is the same as `$status1`. This is a variable variable.

Read about variable variables - http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

#### An alternative solution

Multidimensional arrays are probably an easier way to manage your data.

For example, instead of somthing like

```
$values['status'.$i] = $newStatus[$i];
```

how about

```
$values['status'][$i] = $newStatus[$i];
```

Now we can use the data like,

```
extract($values);

if($status[$i] == 'OUT'){ 
   // do stuff
}
```

#### An alternative solution PLUS

You may even find that you can prepare your status array differently. I'm assuming you're using some sort of loop? If so, these are both equivalent,

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($newStatus); $i++){
    $values['status'][$i] = $newStatus[$i];
}
```

and,

```
$values['status'] = $newStatus;
```

:)